# How to disable the right-click context menu on textboxes in Windows, using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to disable the right-click context menu on textboxes in Windows, using C#? Here's what I've got, but it has some errors.

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {   
       textBox1.ContextMenu.Dispose();               
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in Windows Forms?

Comment: @Ali:yes i want this in windows form

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Perhaps your problem can be better solved with another type of control, say a MaskedTextBox, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ok How..? please give me an example of code

Comment: @AmukSaxena I cannot give you teh codez. Explain what you want to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I want to disable the right click on textbox in windows form... This code (textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled =false; ) is working for this... but i dont know how to do this by MaskedTextBox..
I mean Right Click should not work on textBox

Comment: @AmukSaxena the point I've been trying to make: **WHY do you want to disable right click** on a textbox. The desire to disable the context menu may be a symptom of an underlying problem you wish to solve, and I guess this problem can better be solved differently. A context menu, as its name suggests, shows a useful menu depending on the context. For a textbox, useful can mean text operations like copy and paste. Users expect the menu to be present and to work on every textbox. If you just hide it, it'll confuse the users.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, but i want to remove it from a particular form ..for example user entering the password..so that the user can't copy and paste the password in Login Form..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In that case, the accepted solution does look like the best one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try with

```
textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled =false;
```

> Use the [**`ShortcutsEnabled`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) property to enable or disable the following
>   shortcut key combinations and the **control’s shortcut menu**:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: As a side note, `ShortcutsEnabled = false` also disables CTRL-C CTRL-V. Depending on what OP needs, this could be the best answer, or not a good one. Oh and `ContextMenu = null` does not work at all, you should edit that out, or replace it with `= new ContextMenu();`

Comment: Thank you..
textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled =false;

This code is running awesome!!!!
Thank you for help

Answer (score 10):

Try to do this:

```
textBoxt1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
```